# Count length of string without vowels

Tags: python, string

I've a string:-

```
a = 'abcderui'
```

I want to count the length of the string `a` minus the vowels. What would be the fasstest wat to implement that?

Currently I'm doing:-

```
a = list(a)
for i in a:
    if i in vowels:
        continue
    count +=1
```

Comment: FYI, you **never** have to convert a string to a list unless you want a mutable object holding the chars. Strings already behave like lists when it comes to iterating and accessing elements/slices.

Comment: Don't worry about "fastest", unless a bottleneck *has* been identified

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If strings are not huge then [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) is the best option:

```
>>> a = 'abcderui'
>>> len(a.translate(None, 'aeiou'))
4
```

**Timings:**

```
>>> a = 'abcderui'*100
>>> %timeit len(a.translate(None, 'aeiou'))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.86 µs per loop
>>> %timeit sum(1 for c in a if c not in 'aeiou')
10000 loops, best of 3: 53.2 µs per loop
>>> %timeit len(nonvowels.findall(a))
10000 loops, best of 3: 65.3 µs per loop
>>> %timeit len(vowels.sub('', a))
10000 loops, best of 3: 72 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 3):

Regex solution:

```
import re
nonvowels = re.compile('[^aeiou]', re.IGNORECASE)
result = len(nonvowels.findall(s))
```

or

```
vowels = re.compile('[aeiou]', re.IGNORECASE)
result = len(vowels.sub('', s))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sum(1 for c in some_string if c not in 'aeiou')
```

If you want the string without vowels, too, simply use a list comprehension instead of `sum` and `c` instead of `1`.

But note that different languages have different vowels!

Comment: or `sum(c not in 'aeiou' for c in some_string)`

Comment: That's actually a pretty nice idea - but in terms of readability I believe making use of the fact that bools are int subclasses is not the first choice.